# How to Delimit an Array and Reference the String in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below I have a script which will send an email (from excel) to the recipients listed in the Mail.To variable. I would like to pull a list of email addresses from an array in a different worksheet, delimit the values, and seperate them with a semicolon.

I am getting a run-time error with the current code: 
 '-2147352565 (8002000b)'
 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

Am I going about this the right way? (using the join function). Or is there a more simple way.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
Private Sub sendEmail_Click()
 Dim Mail As New Message
 Dim config As Configuration
 Set config = Mail.Configuration

 config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
 config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
 config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
 config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
 config(cdoSendUserName) = "****************.edu"
 config(cdoSendPassword) = "*******"
 config.Fields.Update

 mailRecipientArray = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("D2"),   Range("D20")).Value
 mailRecipientString = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(mailRecipientArray), "; ")

 Mail.To = mailRecipientString
 Mail.From = config(cdoSendUserName)
 Mail.Subject = "EmailSubject"
 Mail.TextBody = ActiveSheet.emailBodytext

 Mail.AddAttachment "C:\Users\fms0ce\Documents\21.txt"

 On Error Resume Next

 Mail.Send

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "There was an error"
  Exit Sub

 End If

MsgBox "Your email(s) have been sent!", vbInformation, "Sent"

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: The 'mailrecipientarray' line

Comment: I Did. But excel still knows it is sheet2. However after changing the name the line displays a runtime error '1004 Application defined or object defined error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Range()` that you are using inside the outer `Range()` still refer to the active sheet. Try:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
mailRecipientArray = ws.Range(ws.Range("D2"), ws.Range("D20")).Value
```

As far as your other question goes, `Join` seems fine. It is one of my favorite functions. If you are having trouble with it, ask another question.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Simple fix. Thanks!
The join function works perfectly.